# Overriding fetch in Marionette.js model (and responding to push updates)

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

This is a two part question.  We have a Marionette.js application wherein, on initial load, we need to "subscribe" to a Lightstreamer instance and keep that instance/connection open (not important what Lightstreamer is except that it sends updates down to the page). Subsequent model updates will generally be triggered not by user actions by by updates coming from Lightstreamer.  I'm at something of a loss as to how to architect this.

Firstly, it seems like the default model fetch() action makes a web request to the model's url property and retrieves data synchronously (in most samples) based on a user action.  For us, the fetch is essentially the "subscribe" action and the initial data (a collection of messages) will be returned asynchronously.  I have seen suggestions to use jquery deferred, but I'm not sure where the done() function goes (in the model? in the module?).

Secondly, it seems like we'd use wreqr somehow to register for the push updates, but I'm also not sure what that would look like.

Here's some psuedo code:

```
MyApp.Lightstreamer = codeToGetTheLightstreamerWiredUp();

MyApp.MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyApp.Message,
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.id = options.id;
  },
  fetch: function () {
    MyApp.Lightstreamer.Do('subscribeUpdate'), {
      adapterName: 'AdapterName',
      parameterValue: this.id,
      otherStuff:  'otherstuff',
      onUpdate: callbackFunction
  }
});

MyApp.module("MyApp"...) {
  MyApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend(
    {
       appRoutes: { 'controller/view/:id', 'subscribe' }
    }
  );

  var Api = {
     subscribe: function(id) {
       var messages = new MyApp.MyMessages({ id: id });
       var deferred = $.Deferred();
       messages.fetch({
         success: deferred.resolve
       }
     }
  };

  QaApp.addInitializer(function () {
      var router = new QaApp.Router(
      {
          controller: Api
      });
  });
}
```

1. Question 1:  where does the callbackFunction and/or how does
   deferred work in this case
2. Question 2:  how do I update this model
   when a push event happens that has new data (e.g., a new message to
   add to the collection)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone's native `fetch` implementation can provide a template for you to follow. During a normal fetch, Backbone calls `sync`, passing in the following success callback:

```
  options.success = function(resp) {
    var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
    collection[method](resp, options);
    if (success) success(collection, resp, options);
    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
  };
```

Basically, when Backbone gets a response from the server, it uses this to populate the collection. Since you're getting periodic updates directly from the server, you'll want to do something a lot like this using LightStreamer's `onUpdate` parameter. Backbone either calls `set` or `reset`. `reset` will clear the collection and that sounds undesirable so you can remove the conditional and just call `set`. Triggering `sync` is optional but I'd recommend it for maximum compatibility with Marionette. I don't believe you need to worry about the deferred, unless there's some other requirement I'm missing.

Here's what I suggest:

```
MyApp.Lightstreamer = codeToGetTheLightstreamerWiredUp();

MyApp.MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyApp.Message,
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.id = options.id;
    // not sure if you need this but just in case LightStream changes the context on you
    _.bindAll(this, 'syncLightstreamResponse');
  },
  subscribeToLightStream: function () {
    MyApp.Lightstreamer.Do('subscribeUpdate'), {
      adapterName: 'AdapterName',
      parameterValue: this.id,
      otherStuff:  'otherstuff',
      onUpdate: this.syncLightstreamResponse
  },
  syncLightstreamResponse: function(resp, /* I'm guessing here; update param list as needed */) {
    collection.set(resp, options);
    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
  }
});

MyApp.module("MyApp"...) {
  MyApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend(
    {
       appRoutes: { 'controller/view/:id', 'subscribe' }
    }
  );

  var Api = {
     subscribe: function(id) {
       var messages = new MyApp.MyMessages({ id: id });
       // No need for deferred here; just subscribe
       messages.subscribeToLightStream();
     }
  };

  QaApp.addInitializer(function () {
      var router = new QaApp.Router({
          controller: Api
      });
  });
}
```

It doesn't sound to me like you're really changing the `fetch` behavior so much as creating an alternative mechanism for synching the collection with the server; the point being that I don't think you need to override `fetch` to accomplish your goal. I've renamed your function to `subscribeToLightStream`, but it shouldn't matter if choose to override `fetch` instead.

Comment: That looks right, thanks!  Now, if I can get my routes firing properly, I can actually test it (-:

Comment: Glad to help. If you post your routing issue I'll take a look and see if I can help there too.

Comment: Finally got routing working just minutes ago, and this is *almost* working, but in the syncLightstreamerResponse method, I am getting "collection is not defined." Inspecting "this" shows that "this" is the Lightstreamer adapter object.

Comment: Got some help from the guy who wrote the lightstreamer update code and worked out some very strange scoping issues and it's all good now.  Thanks, Chris!

Comment: Awesome - no problem!

Comment: In case you look at this again, I posted a follow-up here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650469/how-to-dynamically-update-a-marionette-collectionview-when-the-underlying-model .  I am having an issue w/the view not refreshing - probably simple.  Anyway, thanks again.